# Opening map (*.mxd) using ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, mxd, online-viewer

I created a map yesterday using ArcMap on my laptop.

I do not have access to the programme right now.

Is it possible to open this map (mxd) file on ArcGIS online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would've had to have published your data onto AGOL in order to create a similar map to what you did in ArcMap on your laptop.

Without first putting the map/data onto AGOL, you are unable to view your map.